# Probability of selecting specific questions out of a group

Tags: probability

Given 6 questions that could possibly appear on an exam. 4 of the 6 will be selected to appear on the exam. Of the 4 that appear on the exam, 2 must be answered.

You have the question list in advance so you can prepare some answers. If you prepare answers to 3 questions what is the probability that at least two of the questions you study will appear on the exam?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Total number of combinations (selected questions and prepared questions):
$$
N=C^6_4C^6_3=\frac{6!}{4!2!}\frac{6!}{3!3!}=300
$$
Numbers of combinatonions in which two or three prepared questions are among selected respectively:
$$
W_2=C^6_4C^4_2C^2_1=\frac{6!}{4!2!}\frac{4!}{2!2!}\frac{2!}{1!1!}=180\\
W_3=C^6_4C^4_3C^2_0=\frac{6!}{4!2!}\frac{4!}{3!1!}\frac{2!}{0!2!}=60
$$
Then, probability:
$$
\frac{W_2+W_3}{N}=\frac{180+60}{300}=\frac{4}{5}=0.8
$$

Comment: Can you explain why W2/W3 have the extra choose at the end (2 choose 1/0)?

Comment: @Steven: for example, in $W_2$ we choose $2$ questions from group of selected $(4)$ and choose $1$ question from group of not selected $(2)$